# NServiceBus v3.3 and v4.0 compatibility

Tags: nservicebus

I have a self hosted (IIS) NServiceBus process that runs NServiceBus 3.3.3.

I am going to be creating another process in IIS (on the same machine) that will take messages from the 3.3.3 version.  I would like to make the new one be version 4.0.4 (the latest release).

**Does anyone know if I will have compatibility problems sending from 3.3.3 to 4.0.4?**

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any problems.
Version N <-> N+1 are always backwards compatible on the wire.

If you find any issues, please raise it in Github and we will fix it!